# How to Remove Question Mark from between the strings

Tags: .htaccess

Somehow Google indexed one of the pages as
domain.com/string?string
How can I rewrite it to
domain.com/string
So, need to remove ?string from the url.
Tried many ways but didn't help.

Thank you in advance.

Already tried
RewriteRule ^string?string$ /string [L,R=301]
but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match parts of the query string with a `RewriteRule`. That is clearly documented. And shown in an endless number of existing answers here on SO.

Instead you need the assistance of a `RewriteCond` and explicitly delete the query string:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^string$
RewriteRule ^/?string/?$ /string [QSD,L,R=301]
```

In general you should implement such rules in the central http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that (read: if you are using a cheap hosting provider) you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (often named ".htaccess"), if the interpretation of such files in enabled in general and if you configured the option to overwrite rules in such files (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation).

In addition you should consider *why* Google has been able to catalog such a URL. That means that the robot found a link to that URL somewhere. That is what you should take care of too. You still have to implement the redirection to prevent a scoring penalty, but certainly you want to fix the cause, not just handle the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove any `?string` from URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R,L]
```